# Why is my multiplication of matrices crashing in my program?

Tags: c, matrix

I've run into a bit of trouble in my program. I'm sure it has something to do with memory but I can't pinpoint the exact cause of the crash. In my program, I have two long float matrices that I would like to multiply together. One matrix is 7x1 (7 rows 1 column) and the other is 7x7 (7 rows and 7 columns). Both of the matrices are named matrixY and matrixY respectively.

Matrix T:

```
49244824435.000000 119389046816.250000 39946687622.000000 134033754390.000000 113174866996.000000 272947307571.500000 57145173936.250000
119389046816.250000 289454411315.062500 96845750191.250000 324960870933.750000 274388194250.500000 661757833373.125000 138543299809.062500
39946687622.000000 96845750191.250000 32404329394.000000 108725307556.000000 91805134479.000000 221408041345.500000 46355176893.250000
134033754390.000000 324960870933.750000 108725307556.000000 364823702850.000000 308047197273.000000 742934555194.500000 155537281593.750000
113174866996.000000 274388194250.500000 91805134479.000000 308047197273.000000 260106770582.000000 627313081608.000000 131331845278.500000
272947307571.500000 661757833373.125000 221408041345.500000 742934555194.500000 627313081608.000000 1512933380437.250000 316738287317.125000
57145173936.250000 138543299809.062500 46355176893.250000 155537281593.750000 131331845278.500000 316738287317.125000 66313171264.062500
```

Matrix Y:

```
3.000000
3.000000
2.000000
4.000000
3.000000
4.000000
3.000000
```

Both matrices are from an input file at the start of my program. I used a printf to make sure the matrices are in fact 2D arrays and stored in memory. Because my program is sort of lengthy, I will post the snippet of code that relates to the multiplication. I have two variables named row and dimension that finds the row and dimensions of the first matrix.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int row;
    int column;
   /*code that takes input from file and scans into matrix*/

   /*code that finds dimensions of matrix and stores in a variable **row** and **column***/
   /*more code that performs other unrelated tasks*/

    /*CREATE PROFUCT MATRIX AND ALLOCATE MEMORY*/
    double **productMatrixY;
    printf("created product matrix Y: \n");

    productMatrixY = (double **)malloc(row*sizeof(double));
    for(i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        productMatrixY[i] = malloc(column*sizeof(double)); /*original was column instead of row*/
    }

    /*Multiply both matrices*/

    sum = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < row; i++) /*originally 'row'*/
        {
            productMatrixY[i][j] = 0;
            for(k = 0; k < column; k++)
            {
                sum += matrixT[i][k] * matrixY[k][j];
            }
            productMatrixY[i][j] = sum;
            sum = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("multiplied TRANSPOSE and MATRIX Y\n");
    {
        productMatrixY[i] = malloc(column*sizeof(double)); 
    }
    printf("allocated memory for product matrix Y:\n");
    printf("\n");
```

The code crashes as soon as the multiplication begins. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Looks like you are allocating the rows after you try to access them??

Comment: You multiply `sum += matrixT[i][k] * matrixY[k][j];`. But isn't MatrixY monodimensional? So what do you expect using two indexes?

Comment: The first `malloc` line with `productMatrixY = malloc(row*sizeof(double));` should be with `sizeof(double*)`

Comment: @Cubo78 `productMatrixY` is supposed to be an array of pointers, not a 2D array.

Comment: I've seen the `double **` declaration, but I've also read the problem description above, and it talks about a 7×1 matrix. Ok, I surrender.

Comment: You need to do some more work on the [mcve]. The `malloc` in braces after a `printf` makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: In your second for loop, `for (j = 0; j < row; i++)` you are incrementing `i` instead of `j`.